# How can I put data on sharepoint list using Rest

Tags: javascript, rest, sharepoint-2013

I can make requests with GET method and work with the data but now I need to make a html form in SharePoint and submit using javascript to a SharePoint list. Any help?

```
    PostFormBuilder.RESTPost = function (listTitle, query) {
    var execute = function (listTitle, query) {
        var restUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl +
            "/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('" + listTitle + "')/items";
        if (query != "") {
            restUrl = restUrl + "?" + query;
        }
        var deferred = $.ajax({
            url: restUrl,
            method: "POST",
            body: { '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Data.Modelo' }, 'Title': 'Test'},
            headers: {
                Authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken,
                "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "X-RequestDigest": jQuery("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
                "IF-MATCH": "*",
                "X-Http-Method": "MERGE"
            }
        });

        return deferred.promise()
    };

    return {
        execute: execute
    }
}();
```

Comment: What are you having problems with?  There is a ton of documentation out there. For example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj164022.aspx#WritingData

Comment: The link you show only have the code to create a list. I need to fill the list using a form.

Comment: This link is in the additional resources section: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn292552.aspx#ListItems.  Give it a shot yourself and post the code you are using if you are can't get it working.

Comment: I put the code, doesent work. Something in the code as wrong?

Comment: Are you getting an error in the console?  You may also want to check the response you get from the AJAX to see if you are getting a response code or error message that may help.